# FitNesse: Comparing data in Slim Test system

Tags: fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

Table example:

```
!script|SomeTest           |
|Goto  |$Url               |
|check |IsAt|IndexPage|true|
|Index |CheckUserOrder?    |
|0     |Name1              |
|1     |Name2              |
```

Code example:

```
public class SomeTest {
 public string index;
 public bool IsAt(string pageTitle){
    //function for checking title of page
 }
 public string CheckUserOrder{
     return username(index); // will get name of user for list which is other class
 }
}
```

An exception is thrown: `method name '0' not found in SomeTest...`

I don't know why FitNesse is considering '0' as a method and not a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with the Slim test system?  ColumnFixture requires the Fit test system. http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSystems

With Slim test system, use the DecisionTable http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.DecisionTable

So your test will look like:

```
!|script|SomeTest|
|Goto|$Url|
|check|IsAt|IndexPage|true|

!|SomeTest|
|Index|CheckUserOrder?|
|0|Name1|
|1|Name2|
```

Comment: I am using Slim and have edited my code. Issue is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine a script and a decission table. If you are doing a script table, I expect you would have:

```
!|script|SomeTest|
|Goto|$Url|
|check|IsAt|IndexPage|true|
|check|CheckUserOrder|0|Name1|
|check|CheckUserOrder|1|Name2|
```